# Version-independent code for Rfc2898DeriveBytes (has Dispose on .NET 4.0 but not on 2.0)

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, using

I'm writing a small .NET 2.0 compatible assembly which uses `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`. On .NET 2.0 `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` does not implement `IDisposable`, while in .NET 4.0 `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` does implement `IDisposable`.

My assembly is loaded in .NET 4.0 applications and in .NET 2.0 applications.

**Do I need to `Dispose` `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` using .NET 4.0 or can I just ignore it like with `MemoryStream`? If so, how can I write .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 compatible code, calling `Dispose` only on .NET 4.0? (At best without reflection and so on.)**

I guess not using `Dispose` on that class is not dangerous because `IDisposable` comes from the `abstract` `DeriveBytes`-class.

Comment: If you look at the source code, the `Dispose()` disposes the internal `HMACSHA1` hasher and clears the (as in `Array.Clear`) the buffer with the result bytes and the `salt`.

Comment: @xanatos: It looks like `HMACSHA1`, `HMAC`, `KeyedHashAlgorithm` and `HashAlgorithm` only using `Dispose` to cleanup their hashes and not freeing limited resources. Therefore I guess I can just ignore `Dispose` in that case?

Comment: some persons don't like the fact that the `salt` wasn't "cleared"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could:

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc = null;

try
{
    var salt = new byte[128];
    rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("password", salt);
}
finally
{
    IDisposable disp = rfc as IDisposable;

    if (disp != null)
    {
        disp.Dispose();
    }
}
```

even with Roslyn, the compiler doesn't remove the `as IDisposable`: http://goo.gl/OObkzv (right pane, it is already in Release mode, so with optimizations active)

(note that I'm not exactly replication the `using` pattern... I have initialized the `rfc` variable inside the `try`/`finally` instead of outside... There is probably no practical difference)

Comment: Doesn't `using` do this already regardless if `IDisposable` is implemented or not?

Comment: @leppie `using` gives a compile-time error if the type is not known at compile time to implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: @hvd: Perhaps they should improve it to cater for stuff like this :D

Comment: @leppie Perhaps you/they shouldn't add a `IDisposable` interface... it is considered to be a breaking change. From [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/system.idisposable.aspx): *It is a version-breaking change to add the IDisposable interface to an existing class, because it changes the semantics of the class.*

Comment: @leppie You could write `var rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("password", salt); using (rfc as IDisposable) { ... }` if you think that's more readable. I don't think it would be an improvement to extend the `using` statement to no longer give an error, as I suspect it would merely make people think `using` should always be used, regardless of whether it makes sense.

Comment: @xanatos I can't find your quote on the page you link to. I can find "It is a breaking change to add the IDisposable interface to an existing class. Because pre-existing consumers of your type cannot call Dispose, you cannot be certain that unmanaged resources held by your type will be released." But I don't quite understand the logic used by MS here. The pre-existing consumers that don't call `Dispose()` get exactly the same behaviour as they did in the old version of the class (which is that nothing gets disposed), so if the behaviour doesn't change, how is it a breaking change?

Comment: @hvd Probably different languages of MSDN... The problem is if you add a `IDisposable` because *now* it is needed to call `Dispose()` (like to close a file or free a limited resource). They give a general rule... Clearly in this case it doesn't break anything, but in the most general case, bad things could happen

Comment: @leppieI don't think a `using` that can be used against anything would work (it is doable, but not "good")... From a technical standpoint, the `using` is converted at compile time to a `try`... `finally`..., but you want the CLR at JIT time to decide if use the using (`try`/`finally`) or ignore it... and from a "programmer" standpoint, I want the programmers to know that *those* 20 classes need `using`, so that they learn them by rote and, when they see a `StreamWriter`, the first thing they ask is "where is the `using`"? If everything can be put in the using, you lose this.